# App inventor: Get letter from number place

Tags: android, app-inventor

I do not know how to get the numberth letter in **MIT App Inventor**.
For example if we have "`World`" if I take 2, I need letter `o`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

use the **segment** block, see also the documentation http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/blocks/text.html#segment

[image]

And let me recommend you to use **Do it** to debug your blocks, see also tip 4 here https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php
see also [Live Development, Testing, and Debugging Tools](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/testing.html)

A very good way to learn App Inventor or Kodular is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the [Top 5 Tips: How to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)